# GWT Multi Module Project with Maven - Dev Mode

Tags: java, maven, gwt

I'm having trouble in running multi-module gwt project in Dev Mode using both command line and in Eclipse:

1. Getting the below error in Dev Mode when I tried to run (mvn gwt:run -Ddev)  the GWT multi module project created using the modular-webapp archetype:

   ```
   00:00:14.244 [DEBUG] Linking module 'gwtapp'    
   00:00:14.244 [DEBUG] Linking module 'gwtapp'
   00:00:14.244 [TRACE] Linking Public artifacts into C:\work\mvn-workspace\modular-gwtapp\modular-gwtapp-client\target\modular-gwtapp-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT

   00:00:14.244 [DEBUG] Emitting resource gwtapp.devmode.js
   00:00:14.244  [ERROR] Fatal error emitting artifact: gwtapp.devmode.js

   java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\work\mvn-workspace\modular-gwtapp\modular-gwtapp-client\target\modular-gwtapp-client-1.0-SNAPSHOT\gwtapp\gwtapp.devmode.js (The requested operation cannot be performed on a file with a user-mapped section open)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
   at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
   at com.google.gwt.dev.util.OutputFileSetOnDirectory$1.<init>(OutputFileSetOnDirectory.java:55)
   at com.google.gwt.dev.util.OutputFileSetOnDirectory.createNewOutputStream(OutputFileSetOnDirectory.java:55)
   at com.google.gwt.dev.util.OutputFileSet.openForWrite(OutputFileSet.java:82)
   at com.google.gwt.core.ext.linker.impl.StandardLinkerContext.produceOutput(StandardLinkerContext.java:508)
   at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.produceOutput(DevMode.java:588)
   at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.link(DevModeBase.java:1010)
   at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.createArtifactAcceptor(DevModeBase.java:1153)
   at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.doCreateShellModuleSpaceHost(DevModeBase.java:886)
   at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase$UiBrowserWidgetHostImpl.createModuleSpaceHost(DevModeBase.java:105)
   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:197)
   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:526)
   at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:364)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

   00:00:14.245  [ERROR] Failed to load module 'gwtapp' from user agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3; rv:11.0) like Gecko' at 127.0.0.1:49922
   ```
2. Below are the steps that I followed to create the sample modular-webapp:

   1.

   ```
       mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/ -DarchetypeGroupId=net.ltgt.gwt.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=modular-webapp -DarchetypeVersion=1.0-SNAPSHOT
       groupId: com.bala.gwtapp
       artifactId: modular-gwtapp
       version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
       package: com.bala.gwtapp
       module: App
       module-short-name: gwtapp
   ```

   2. `mvn clean install -Dgwt.compiler.skip`
   3. Terminal Window-1: `cd *-client and mvn gwt:run -Ddev`
   4. Terminal Window-2: `cd *-server and mvn jetty:start -Ddev`
3. How to Run this multi module application in IDE (Eclipse) using RunAs configuration.  An example configuration would be appreciated
   Followed below steps for IDE:

   1. Used the same project created in step 2.1 above
   2. Created eclipse configuration using mvn eclipse:eclipse and imported as Maven project into eclipse.
   3. Created a new configuration under Run As Configuration -> Web Application
   4. Client code executes fine, however, unable to get the response from RPC (GWT) Implementation.  It shows the server response error message (onFailure()) in the response dialogue.
4. How to Debug the multi module application in IDE (Eclipse) - Ex: an example configuration would be appreciated
5. Is it possible to attach debugger from the command line using mvn gwt:debug
6. Also, its showing the below warning when the application executed using maven in cmd line:

   ```
   [WARNING] Your POM <build><outputdirectory> does not match your hosted webapp WEB-INF/classes folder for GWT Hosted browser to see your classes
   ```

NOTE: It works fine in the Super Dev mode - tested using command line.

I need to sort out these issues so as to implement this multi-module approach for our application.

Thanks in advance.